# What's the expected value of the average of this set of numbers, when split into odds and evens?

Tags: probability

This question is a hypothetical I came up with for myself and it's about expected value. You start with a list of $n$ positive integers. Each one is randomly and uniformly selected to be some number from $1$ to $n$. Then you split these into two lists, one containing only the odd numbers and the other having even numbers. If $O$ is the average of the odd numbers and $E$ is the average of the even numbers, then $Y = \frac{O + E}{2}$. What is $E(Y)$?

Edit: If all numbers turn out to be the same parity, the empty list has an average of zero.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried some small $n?$

Comment: How do you define the average of the odd (or even) numbers in the event when you don’t select any odd (or even) numbers?

Comment: In any event, this amounts to calculating $E(O)$ and $E(E)$ and then take the average. The formula will depend somewhat on whether $n$ is odd or even, and what your values are when you get no odd value or no even value.

Comment: To be honest, I only understand expectation on a simple level, could you explain why the problem simplifies to the average of $E(O)$ and $E(E)$?

Comment: Removing $2$, we have $Y = O + E$, thus $\mathbb E(Y) = \mathbb E(O) + \mathbb E(E)$ - it's true even if $O$ and $E$ are not independent.